# Cannot get the uml package to work

Tags: uml

The `uml` package (uml.sty) seems well documented, but The first (very simple) code example that I tried gives errors:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{uml}
\begin{document}
\umlDiagram[box=,border,sizeX=7cm,sizeY=4cm]{%
\umlClass[refpoint=bl, pos={3,3}]{ClassName}{}{}}   
\end{document}
```

I tried wrapping it, but it doesn't work. I use `MikTeX` on a Windows machine. The graphics in the documentation look nice, so I would like to use them. What am I missing here?

Comment: You need to compile your document with LaTeX or XeLaTeX, not with pdfLaTeX. Are you doing that?

Comment: No, I am using pdfLaTeX (and plan to do so in the future). Why should that be a problem?

Comment: The [documentation](//texdoc.net/pkg/uml) mentions "`uml.sty` relies heavily on the LaTeX packages `pstricks` and `pst-node` [PSTricks]. Most of the graphics
is displayed using `pstricks`" (section **29.3 Using other packages**, p 40). It therefore requires a different compiler.

Comment: you could also try with lualatex, in current tex systems it supports most of pstricks.

Comment: I am an old man and grew up in the days that pdflatex was simply latex with a different post processor and could do exactly the same. I didn't know they grew apart. What a pity.

Comment: @MichelJanssens no: pdflatex was never a post processor, it diverged when it was first introduced in the 1990s. pstricks has never worked with pdflatex, you can use now what you used then, latex, dvips, pstopdf, so there is a postscript post processor

Comment: I am just stating what I remember. I did not say it was merely a postprocessor. I am sorry if I stepped on some toes here. I have stopped answering questions because I was affraid to make people angry (I did make a mistake in the past.) . I guess I have to stop asking questions as well. I guess I am just too old for these discussion boards. Again, my apologies.